# Is using type unsigned char acceptable when only a small number is needed?

Tags: c, variables, memory-management, integer

If writing a program, and I need a number that is lower than 255, is it ok to use type `unsigned char` for use as a number, such as if I need a number to make a loop? Is there any reason, including sticking to tradition and convention, to stick to declaring numbers with int and float, etc.

For example, should code like this never be used? Or would it be good practice to use an unsigned char in this case, since it allocates less memory than a short int?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char short_loop;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  short_loop i;

  for(i = 0; i < 138; i++)
      printf("StackOverflow Example Code\n");

  return 0;
}
```

I'm asking for future reference, and only using the code above to help illustrate.

Comment: It is really only good practice when it is for example a large array of small numbers. Using one char instead of one int will make almost zero difference on total memory

Comment: A char is an integer type, why wouldn't it be useful to store a number?  See [this](/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double) for a discussion on performance differences between built in types.  Using your 8 bit int may actually be slower than using a larger one

Comment: Are there any reason **not** to stick to `int`? Your code works fine but what do you think you'll gain from using `unsigned char` instead of `int`? In most cases it doesn't matter at all as modern compilers will just do whatever is "best" for your specific system.

Comment: If you're working with a team, they will strongly dislike you for doing this. First, because of the needless typedef that obfuscates the fact that you're using an unusual type for the loop variable. And second, because it creates a maintenance nightmare. If the array size increases to 500 entries, none of your coworkers would expect that they need to change the type of the loop variable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. Sounds like I'd be best sticking to int.

Comment: You're talking about char, yet your example is showing unsigned char. That's confusing.

Comment: @2501 Thanks for pointing that out. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do it.

If your program is working with large arrays of values, then there is a benefit in terms of memory usage of using an array of `char` rather than an array of `int`.

But, for the control variable of a single loop, there is unlikely to be much benefit, and potentially a performance hit, for several reasons.

Comparing `i < 138` will promote `i` to `int` before doing the comparison, since `138` is of type `int`.    Promotions (and down-conversions) also potentially occur with initialising and incrementing `i` as well.

`int` is typically the "native type" on the host machine - which normally means it is a type that is preferred on the host (e.g. hardware provides registers that are optimised for performance when operating on that type).  Which, even if some technique is used to prevent promotion of `unsigned char` to `int` before doing the comparisons in the loop, operations on `int` may be more effective anyway.

So, in the end, your approach might or might not give a performance benefit.  The only way to be sure would be to profile the code .... and the benefits (or otherwise) would be compiler dependent (e.g. affected by optimisation approaches) and host dependent (e.g. how efficient are operations on `unsigned char` in comparison with operations on `int`)

Your approach also makes the code harder to understand, and therefore harder to get right.    And, if some other programmer (or you) modify the code in future, any benefit may be negated .... for example, by accidentally reintroducing unintended type conversions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using `unsigned char` is fine. I would not use the `short_loop` typedef though, it just obfuscates the code for no reason.

Some would recommend using `uint8_t` to emphasize that the intent is a small integer, instead of character data; even though `uint8_t` is very likely to be a typedef for `unsigned char`.

Theoretically you could use the typedef `uint_fast8_t`, which is supposed to mean "an unsigned integer type, at least 8 bits, and the fastest possible of the available types"  , obviously the interpretation of "fastest" is a bit vague.

Comment: Do you recommend using uint8_t ?

Comment: @Malina I'd use `int` personally but it is more a matter of personal preference than any compelling technical reason.

Comment: Using anything other than int is not very conventional. And `uint8_t` is not guaranteed to exist. This premature optimization (in terms of memory) gives less readability and requires modifications if the literal is to be increased over 255. In a lot programs it is definition to avoid magic numbers and in some cases to allow customization as if we want to print our own times the string. It will have to explicitly convert the literal probably two times in the loop (hence optimizations in the family of BP) which is - for performance. But not significant. Just like the 3 bytes saving.

Comment: @Malina `uint_fast8_t` addresses those concerns. `int` does not fix any of those problems, it just shifts the failure point from `255` to `32767`.  I program some systems with less than 2K of usable stack, in those cases the 3-byte saving is worthwhile

Comment: You are right, but usage of `uint_fast8_t`  forbids NAIs. Not very practical and universal approach. Well yes if the main purpose is to use as low memory as possible. (Also I believe you meant `short` not `int`)

Comment: It might be good to mention using `size_t` as the type for loop variables since it's quite common to compare them to the return value from `sizeof()` and it is also an integer type

Answer (score 1):

For use with PC - not very good practice.
For use in embedded device - depends.

If it is guaranteed that it will not exceed 255, then sure you can use it as it is converted to an int anyway, but the memory difference is not very significant in this example.

It violates readability.

---

And as others said you are obfuscating your code unnecessarily.
With the type definition.. giving it ugly name too.
indexes are known to be of type int. And that's all.